# How to read relations from Json file while using apoc.load.json() in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, sqlcipher, neo4j-apoc

I want to read relations from my Json file instead of hard coding them.

for example: 
instead of

```
MERGE (arg1)-[:relation]->(arg2)
```

I want to have something like:

```
MERGE (arg1)-[:v.relation]->(arg2).
```

My Json file is as following:

```
{
  "bacf06771e0f4fc5a8e68c30fc77c9c4": {

    "arg1": "the Treasury",
    "arg2": "details of the November refunding",
    "relation": "will announce",
    "id": "bacf06771e0f4fc5a8e68c30fc77c9c4",
    "linkedContexts": [
      {
        "targetID": "948eeebd73564adab7dee5c6f177b3b9",
        "classification": "CONTRAST"
      }
    ]  


  },

  "948eeebd73564adab7dee5c6f177b3b9": {

    "arg1": "the funding",
    "arg2": "",
    "relation": "will be delayed",
    "id": "948eeebd73564adab7dee5c6f177b3b9",
    "linkedContexts": [
      {
        "targetID": "006a71e51295440fab7a8e8c697d2ba6",
        "classification": "CONDITION"
      }

    ]    

  }
}
```

I tried:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("files:///example.json") YIELD value
UNWIND [k IN KEYS(value) | value[k]] AS v
MERGE (arg1:Arg1 {subject:v.arg1}) 
MERGE (arg2:Arg2 {object:v.arg2}) 
MERGE (arg1)-[:v.relation]->(arg2)
```

I got this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '.': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '|', a length specification, a property map or ']' (line 13, column 17 (offset: 444))
"merge (arg1)-[:v.relation]->(arg2) "
                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to create relationships dynamically with Cypher.

You can use [apoc's apoc.merge.relationship procedure](https://dzone.com/articles/summer-2017-release-of-the-apoc-procedures-library) to create nodes/relationships dynamically.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("files:///example.json") YIELD value
UNWIND [k IN KEYS(value) | value[k]] AS v
MERGE (arg1:Arg1 {subject:v.arg1}) 
MERGE (arg2:Arg2 {object:v.arg2}) 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(arg1,v.relation,{},{},arg2) YIELD rel
RETURN count(*);
```